# Migrating from devise to omniauth (identity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, omniauth

I'm thinking of moving over to Omniauth 1.0 (using the "identity" strategy or gem) from Devise 1.4.7, my question is after doing all the code conversion, views etc, will the old passwords, those user accounts created with Devise, still work with the same passwords under OmniAuth?

I've done some research and both are using bcrypt, so I'm guessing "yes" they will work as before and users won't have to create new passwords. Or am I missing something crucial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Devise passwords are not *directly* compatible with omniauth-identity**

It is true that they both use bcrypt to hash the password, however Devise adds a "pepper" to the password. You would have to add code to omniauth-identity to support a "pepper".

- OmniAuth-Identity - [lib/omniauth/identity/secure_password.rb](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity/blob/master/lib/omniauth/identity/secure_password.rb#L60)
- Devise - [lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L41)

#### Pepper your passwords

Devise adds a pepper to your passwords (since it is already salted by bcrypt), so in order for you to migrate devise users to omniauth-identity, you have to teach the identity strategy how to pepper passwords. This snippit works for us, however we didn't change the :stretches configuration option in devise.

```
# snatch the pepper setting from the devise initializer
pepper = "biglonguglystringfromyourdeviseinitializer"

# password created by devise in your db (i.e. "my_password_123")
encrypted_password = "$2a$10$iU.Br8ZClxuqldJt8Evl5OaBbHPJeBWbGV/1RoUsaNIZMBo8wHYTq" 

# pepper the password then compare it using BCrypt like identity does
BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password) == "my_password_123#{pepper}"
 => true
```

#### How we made it work

This is a very quick and dirty monkey patch we used to make it work. We are investigating how to add this functionality in a more appropriate manner.

```
# file: ~/railsapp/config/initializers/omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity
end


module OmniAuth
  module Identity
    module SecurePassword
      module InstanceMethodsOnActivation
        # Returns self if the password is correct, otherwise false.
        def authenticate(unencrypted_password)
          pepper = "the big pepper string from the devise initializer"
          if BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest) == "#{unencrypted_password}#{pepper}"
            self
          else
            false
          end
        end

        # Encrypts the password into the password_digest attribute.
        def password=(unencrypted_password)
          pepper = "the big pepper string from the devise initializer"
          @password = unencrypted_password
          unless unencrypted_password.empty?
            self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create("#{unencrypted_password}#{pepper}")
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, this makes a lot of sense and I thought pepper was always used with bcrypt. Our moving towards Omniauth was put on hold, but this will come in useful in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are missing anything crucial at all. Both are using `bcrypt`. Awesome.
 **But does that matter ?** I think it really does.

Devise completes your authentication process w.r.t to a Model i.e. say `users` in this case.

Now your old users are already registered and confirmed, so that really wouldn't be an issue. The `encrypted_password` and `hashed_password` are still in the users table for the users to access.

**What do you have to worry about ?**

=> You probably have to worry about the `authenticate_user!` filter. I am guessing since they both use `bcrypt` the authentication wouldn't really be an issue. Perhaps if `OmniAuth` isn't, they the way it authenticates users would be completely different and your code will break apart.

Thats the only thing you will have to look after is what i feel.